# IntelliJ persumabely indexes in the wrong way: compiler works, but IDEA does not fain Main method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently, after updating IntelliJ I started getting a warning on one my computers, in command-line Java projects, that `Main method not found in class com.company.Main`. I started a new sample project using *JBoss > Create from project template > Command Line App*. I have the same error. This is my Run/Debug configuration: [image] The strange thing is that building or debugging works just fine from terminal and using IntelliJ GUI as well. The following is the sample project I made to try and find a solution: [image] I tried re-adding different JDKs, also ivalidating caches and restarting, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like some issue with the project JDK configuration, notice the red exclamation mark on the top right of the editor. What does it say? Does it help if you remove the JDK configuration and add it again, then make sure that the project and module have this new JDK in the dependencies? Please also try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, I tried removing and re-adding JDK configuration. What is more I tried adding different JDK configs, including JBR. Just now, I have used File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart, but it did not work either.

Comment: What does the error in the editor say?

Comment: When howering my mouse on `String` it says, that `Cannot resolve symbol String`. Other than that it only writes that warning in the config window.

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of the JDK configuration | Classpath tab, the project JDK and the JDK for the modules in the dependencies? Your IDE is rendered incorrectly, there may be some issue with the installation as well. I'd suggest reinstalling from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. Also try running with the clean configs.

Comment: I clean installed my OS, now it works, but unfortunately I can not show you it anymore.